# Count how many times a number divides another number

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I am trying to count how many 2 divides 100. When I run this code, I got the output of 1 and 2. Can anyone kindly explain how it is 1 2? I know I am using a count to keep tracking of the division but in the while loop how does it work?

```
int x = 100;
int count = 0;

while (x % 2 == 0)
{
    x = x / 2;
    count++;
    printf("%d", count);
}
```

Comment: You do not get `12` but a `1` followed by a `2`.

Comment: `25 % 2` is not equal to `0`. So just like @alk said.

Comment: As @alk pointed out, you print **inside** your loop.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this in 1 operation ?

Answer (score 2):

You do not get `12` but a `1` followed by a `2`.

Change this

```
  printf("%d", count);
```

to be

```
  printf("%d: x = %d\n", count, x);
```

and become enlightened. ;)

Comment: @Shudha: And when you are already enlightened make sure that your print your counter outside of your loop.

Comment: Got it @alk. Sorry, I made a mistake. It should have been 1 and then 2. I debugged it and saw it in step by steps. Your edit and change helped really. Thanks.

Comment: @ShuddhaChowdhury: There definitely is not need to excuse, happy to help. Debugging is an art, on any level of abstraction.

Comment: When I print count outside of the loop, I got this  "0: x = 50
1: x = 25
2" . Thanks again.